# How to send apple identityToken to server for app launch eveytime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I implemented Sign in with Apple in my App, After successful login, I'm getting identityToken, userid, and sending these values to my backend server for verifying the user. But in my app we have auto-login functionality, For every time app launches it will auto-login and redirect to home page, So here also need to send identityToken, userid to the server But identityToken expiring for 24 hours, So how can I get identityToken without showing apple login page? Please help me.

Comment: You can store identityToken in Local and when needed you can use it.

Comment: @Kudos Yes, we can store it Local and use it later, But the problem is it will expire after 24 hours. So the server can't get the details.

Comment: Then I think this should be fixed from API side bcz token is not expired in 24 hours. Normally tokens expire in a week.

Comment: After 1 week also we can get an error right if the user tries to launch the app.

Comment: Is there any way to get the new token when the existing token expires? @Kudos

Comment: Then in this case you need to Sign In again then only you can get new token.

Comment: Can I get a new token using https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token? @Kudos

Comment: We are also facing this issue. I think the correct flow is to use the identity token you get on the client side and send it to server. Server then uses that id token to get the access token and refresh token. Server should store the refresh token for using it in the next autologin scenario. Server can use it to get the access token without id token (which can only be fetched through a login prompt on the client side).